# Cron job run at the wrong time in AIX 7.1

Tags: unix, cron, aix

I had configured my cronjob to run in every first Monday of the month 8:40am as below

```
40 08 1-7 * 1 /fs/test/testtime.sh
```

But it not only run on Monday, it also run on today which is Tuesday.

Is there anything i miss out?

Comment: Should be alright... since "40 08 1-7 * 1 /fs/test/testtime.sh" means it 's running at 08:40 on every day-of-month from 1 through 7 and on Monday. Make sure there's no other cronjob is running concurrently. Could you use "crontab -l" and paste the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page for crontab (my emphasis):

> Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields - day of month, and day of week. If ***both*** fields are restricted (i.e., aren't `*`), the command will be run when ***either*** field matches the current time.
>
> For example, `30 4 1,15 * 5` would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, ***plus*** every Friday.

So, in your case, the job runs on every one of the first seven days in each month, *plus* every Monday.

You can do what you wish by adding an `AND` condition in the command rather than relying on an `OR` condition in the time specification, something like:

```
40 08 1-7 * * test $(date +\%u) -eq 1 && /fs/test/testtime.sh
```

This will run the actual cron job on *all* those days (first seven days in each month) but the *payload* (the script) will only run if the day is Monday.

Comment: May i know what is the word test refer to? Can it be replace with other word? The project name maybe?

Comment: @Ong, `test` is a way to test for a specific condition so, no, it cannot be replaced with some arbitrary word.